# Inline visualforce pages not visible in lightning UI

Tags: visualforce, lightning, inline-visualforce

I have inline `Visualforce Pages` that should be displayed on the Account detail page. When I try to view those inline pages, they do not appear. What do I need to do to see those pages?

Comment: Please check the: Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages on your Visualforce page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please let me try and will get back to you.